# lxml cssselect Python, ошибка в нахождения элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, lxml, cssselect

Имеется код:

```
<td class="a-center">
                            <input type="text" name="super_group[4014]" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Кол-во" class="input-text qty">
</td>
```

Необходимо получить value и придаеть ему значение.

Нахожу его так:

```
stock_status = td_list[2].cssselect('input')[0].get('value')
                    print(stock_status)
                    if(stock_status == 0):
                        print(sdfsdfsdfsdf)
                        stock_status = "Нет в наличии"
                    if (stock_status == 1):
                        print(sdfsdfsdfsdf)
                        stock_status = "Есть"
```

При нахождение 0 или 1, хочу изменить переменную stock_status. Но в условие оно не попадает.

Я пробовал и "0" и просто 0, но в условие оно не заходит.

Может там скрытые символы?

Comment: `print(repr(stock_status))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема у вас была из-за того, что вы проверяли значение на `0` и `1`, которые являлись целыми числами, а значения атрибутов возвращаются как строки, поэтому у вас и не работало.

Можно было так проверить тип значения: `print(type(stock_status))`

Работает:

```
from lxml import html
root = html.fromstring("""
<td class="a-center">
                            <input type="text" name="super_group[4014]" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Кол-во" class="input-text qty">
</td>
""")

stock_status = root.cssselect('input')[0].get('value')
print(stock_status)  # "1"

if stock_status == "0":
    stock_status = "Нет в наличии"
else:
    stock_status = "Есть"

print(stock_status)  # "Есть"
```

---

```
from lxml import html
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://aquapolis.ru/jelektronagrevatel-elecro-titan-optima-plus-380v.html')

root = html.fromstring(rs.content)

for td in root.cssselect('td.a-center'):
    stock_status = td.cssselect('input')[0].get('value')
    print(stock_status)  # "1"

    if stock_status == "0":
        stock_status = "Нет в наличии"
    else:
        stock_status = "Есть"

    print(stock_status)  # "Есть"
```

---

**PS.**

Решил до конца довести пример выше и вот что получилось:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://aquapolis.ru/jelektronagrevatel-elecro-titan-optima-plus-380v.html')
root = html.fromstring(rs.content)


def get_text(node):
    return html.tostring(node, method='text', encoding='unicode').strip()


for tr in root.cssselect('#super-product-table tr'):
    tds = tr.cssselect('td')
    if not tds:
        continue

    name = get_text(tds[0])
    price = get_text(tds[1].cssselect('.price-box > .regular-price > .price')[0])

    value = tds[2].cssselect('input')[0].get('value')
    stock_status = "Нет в наличии" if value == "0" else "Есть"

    print('{:65} | {:16} | {}'.format(name, price, stock_status))
```

Консоль:

```
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-18 18 кВт (380В)   | 211 572,00 руб.  | Есть
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-24 24 кВт (380В)   | 214 638,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-30 30 кВт (380В)   | 217 704,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-36 36 кВт (380В)   | 229 970,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-45 45 кВт (380В)   | 248 367,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-54 54 кВт (380В)   | 251 433,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-60 60 кВт (380В)   | 285 162,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-72 72 кВт (380В)   | 294 361,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-96 96 кВт (380В)   | 358 753,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
Электронагреватель Elecro Titan Optima Plus СP-120 120 кВт (380В) | 397 080,00 руб.  | Нет в наличии
```

Comment: Пробовали добавить условие как у меня?

Comment: Сайт: https://aquapolis.ru/jelektronagrevatel-elecro-titan-optima-plus-380v.html, это количество товаров

Comment: Даже не понял в чем проблема, извините, но заработало)

Comment: Добавил в ответ причину :) Есть помогло -- примите ответ )